# grep on word with colon fails from command output

Tags: bash, grep, eyed3

Can anyone explain why grepping for "artist" returns results, but grepping for "artist:" returns nothing?

**FIRST RESULT:**

```
MacBook-Pro:~ kjesso$ eyed3 ./Music/Deftones/2006\ -\ Saturday\ Night\ Wrist/Deftones\ -\ 02\ -\ Rapture.mp3
Deftones - 02 - Rapture.mp3 [ 5.26 MB ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 03:25 MPEG1, Layer III    [ ~213 kb/s @ 44100 Hz - Joint stereo ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID3 v2.3:
title: Rapture
artist: Deftones
album: Saturday Night Wrist
album artist: None
recording date: 2006
track: 2        genre: Rock (id 17)
Publisher/label: Maverick
```

**SECOND RESULT:**

```
MacBook-Pro:~ kjesso$ eyed3 ./Music/Deftones/2006\ -\ Saturday\ Night\ Wrist/Deftones\ -\ 02\ -\ Rapture.mp3 | grep "artist"
artist: Deftones
album artist: None
```

**THIRD RESULT:**

```
MacBook-Pro:~ kjesso$ eyed3 ./Music/Deftones/2006\ -\ Saturday\ Night\ Wrist/Deftones\ -\ 02\ -\ Rapture.mp3 | grep "artist:"
```

Comment: `artist` and `artist:` give same results for me.  Show exactly how you are invoking `grep`, and maybe give some info about your platform.

Comment: When I copy/paste the example output (your "First Result") into a file and grep ***that*** it works fine. I suspect in the actual raw output there's an invisible control character in between the "artist" and the ":" that isn't getting transferred to Stack Overflow. Maybe dump the output into a file and look with a hex editor?

Comment: @JuanTomas: The grep command is in the SECOND and THIRD examples, you just have to scroll to the right within the code. There is no space or any special characters between the word **artist** and the **colon**.

Comment: Okay, I see it now.  So the big unknown is the `eyed3` command.  Try:  `eyed3 [myMP3file] > tmpfile ; cat -v tmpfile`.  `cat -v` will reveal any non-printing characters in the output.  UPDATE never mind, I can see Votey got the answer.  Nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eyed3 adds some terminal markup for color-coding, so there are a bunch of bytes in the output that aren't visible on your terminal but which the terminal used to determine the color-coding — even if that color-coding is "exactly the same color throughout.

Adding the `--no-color` option would work perfectly:

```
$ eyed3 --no-color ./Music/Deftones/2006\ -\ Saturday\ Night\ Wrist/Deftones\ -\ 02\ -\ Rapture.mp3 | grep "artist:"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you typed that third instance correctly?  It works for me just fine:

```
$ cat foo.txt
Deftones - 02 - Rapture.mp3 [ 5.26 MB ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 03:25 MPEG1, Layer III    [ ~213 kb/s @ 44100 Hz - Joint stereo ]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID3 v2.3:
title: Rapture
artist: Deftones
album: Saturday Night Wrist
album artist: None
recording date: 2006
track: 2        genre: Rock (id 17)
Publisher/label: Maverick

$ cat foo.txt | grep "artist"
artist: Deftones
album artist: None

$ cat foo.txt | grep "artist:"
artist: Deftones
album artist: None
```

Maybe you typed a semicolon instead of a colon by mistake?

```
$ cat foo.txt | grep "artist;"
$
```

Comment: You're right it works when you put it into a text file, I guess this is something to do with the **eyed3** command. Also, no I didn't miss type the colon as a semi-colon. Everything I put into my example is accurate.